# How to recover files deleted by rm -vr?

Tags: rm, data-recovery, deleted-files, extundelete

When looking up a way to uninstall minecraft using console commands, the very first result on google told me to use the command: `rm -vr ~/ .minecraft/*`.

I thought, oh well, I'm specifying the directory so this should work fine. The command proceeded to start deleting every folder in my home directory. Luckily I caught on to what was happening, but not before my aseprite folder got obliterated.

I know for a fact that the folder directory was `/home/kaiser/aseprite/` and I haven't installed or deleted anything in the home directory since. I'm afraid to change anything or restart my computer because I don't want that partition space to be overwritten.

That folder had lots of works in progress that were very important to me, none of it was backed up yet. I am not touching anything until I can get it back.

I am running **Linux Mint XFCE 20.2** on a **1TB HDD**.
My motherboard is a Gigabyte H310M H 2.0.

If there is any way to recover these files please leave your suggestions. As of writing this post they were deleted about 1 hour ago.

**EDIT**: my partition is EXT4 (ver 1.0).

I also have a **saved session** from a few days ago, not sure if that can be used as a restore point though, since I don't think that saved sessions count as backups.

Comment: Essentially, the files are gone. You may look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6698/can-files-directories-deleted-with-rm-be-restored_) for confirmation. Backups of any important files are essential regardless of the operating system.

Comment: Interesting. I tried to find what you found and got `rm -vr ~/. minecraft/*` from Google, but the actual site gives the command without any space after the dot. It looks to me it's Google who injected the space, probably trying to "fix" the text (we use spaces after dots in *literature*, right?). Personally I'm disgusted with a search engine trying to know better what another site wants to communicate. How and why you got a space *before* the dot is a mystery to me. I know this comment is not helpful, sorry. Interesting observation though.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I also did a search for the command line ... I only found one without a space ... https://linuxhint.com/install_minecraft_linux/ ... near bottom of page ... maybe the one you found is a corrupted copy of another web page

Comment: @kaiserkothe boot from a live linux distribution and make an image of your drive ... that way, your data has the best chance of surviving

Comment: @jsotola [This is the first result I get (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFvus.png), I highlighted the space. The link is to [this site](https://www.alphr.com/uninstall-reinstall-minecraft/) and the command is sane there.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski now I see what you mean ... I use https://duckduckgo.com/ instead of google

Comment: In short: you restore them from your latest backup.  What's that you're saying? You don't have a backup.  That's very unfortunate.  Now you know why you should make regular backups. Data that you don't back up is data that you don't care about, that you are willing to lose.  You could also restore from snapshots if you use a snapshot-capable filesystem like btrfs or zfs and make regular snapshots (but note that snapshots aren't a substitute for backups either, they don't help in case of dead drives, fire, flood, or other disasters)

Comment: In addition, this is a good example of why one should 1) prioritize the text of actual pages found in search (click the link in search results) over the "preview", and 2) not trust and apply every command on some random page blindly (this is actually a broader  concept - one should not blindly trust any random page on the web).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have no backups and because it's ext4 you will also not have any snapshots. This will be *extremely* tricky...

"Luckily" by using `rm` you don't actually remove data as in "overwriting with 0-bits" but instead you are just telling the filesystem that these files do no longer exist and this space can be reused.

The best chance you have now is *immediately* shutting the system down, preferably with a hard shutdown so that nothing touches the filesystem.

Onto the recovery phase:
There are multiple methods/programs for this, take a look at `debugfs` and `extundelete` for starters. You will need both luck and time to recover files and most likely you will only recover some of them.

Also, make you sure to make a bit-by-bit copy of the drive to somewhere else before trying to rescue data on it. You can do this with `dd`.